# Bot Framwork - How to pass parameter to promptValidator or add values in the promptValidatorContext- python

Tags: python, botframework

I have waterfall steps. say welcome step, collect data step, validation step.
in collect data step i make a call to db, fetch all the results and save them in step_context.values["Value1"]. Now in validation step, prompt goes to validator which is configured in add_dialog

```
self.add_dialog(
        TextPrompt(
            "age",
            self.age_validator,
        )
    )
```

my validator function,

```
@staticmethod
async def age_validator(prompt_context: PromptValidatorContext) -> bool:
    
    return (
        prompt_context.recognized.succeeded
        and 0 < prompt_context.recognized.value < value1
    )
```

Now, here i need to access Value1 which was taken in "collect data step" which I have saved in step_context.values["Value1"].
How to pass parameters to the validator function?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this. All I have to do is I have to add validations object in promptoptions.

```
return await step_context.prompt(
            "age",
            PromptOptions(
                prompt=MessageFactory.text(msg),
                retry_prompt=MessageFactory.text(
                    msg
                ),
                **validations= data**
            ),
        )
```

data is an object with Value1. I access this object in my age_validator function like this.

```
 data = prompt_context.options.validations
 data.get_value1()
```